# Template'd Interfaces Conflicting

Tags: c#

I am wondering if there is a clever trick to achieve the below code without `IUseCase<in TInput>` and `IUseCase<out TOuput>` conflicting or to simulate these cases.

```
public interface IUseCase<in TInput, out TOutput>
{
   TOutput Execute(TInput input);
}

public interface IUseCase<in TInput>
{
   void Execute(TInput input);
}

public interface IUseCase<out TOutput>
{
    TOutput Execute();
}
```

Comment: Just asking: are you sure you are using `in` and `out` modifiers correctly in the context of the covariance and contravariance?

Comment: I was going off of this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you cannot declare two generic interfaces with same name but different template constraints, although I cannot find proof to that in MSDN and C# language specification.

Compiler would emit 'already contains a definition' error if two types differ only by covariance modifier, or by type constraint. For example, following sample does not compile as well, although generic type have different constraints:

```
public interface IFoo<T> where T : class
{
  T Bar();
}

public interface IFoo<T> where T : struct
{
  void Bar(T x);
}
```

But types considered different if number of generic parameters are different.

So the answer to your question is - no, you cannot do that, unless you rename your interfaces.

Comment: I kind of figured as much but hoped someone had a super neat trick to mimic it. :(

Comment: I ended up just making a EmptyInput interface to fill in the in TInput. It just feels really gross.